# Convert to array the return of jQuery Each and show max value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function and need what she return a array and show the max value present.

```js
var myCell = new_2ELayout.cells("a").cell;

maxHeight = function(){
 $(myCell).find(".dhxform_base").each(function() {
  var formHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
  console.log(formHeight);
 }); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to get an array

```
var myCell = new_2ELayout.cells("a").cell;

var array  = $(myCell).find(".dhxform_base").map(function() {
    return $(this).outerHeight();
}).get();
```

How to get the max value in an array

```
var max = Math.max.apply(null, array);
```

So all together

```
var myCell = new_2ELayout.cells("a").cell;

var maxHeight = function(){
    var array = $(myCell).find(".dhxform_base").map(function() {
        return $(this).outerHeight();
    }).get();

    return Math.max.apply(null, array);
}
```